# Unsure what imports to use for Advanced Marker Element

Tags: google-maps

```
import { GoogleMap, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
  return (
    <div className="student-page">
      <div className='student-page-top-half'>
        {studentId && <StudentInfoBox studentId={studentId} />}
        {/* Map section */}
        {studentCoordinates && (
          <GoogleMap
            id="student-map"
            mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '400px' }}
            center={studentCoordinates}
            zoom={15}
          >
            <Marker position={studentCoordinates} />
          </GoogleMap>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className='student-page-bottom-half'>
        {/* Current Classes section */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I am writing a react component to render a map. I get this deprecation warning and I have seen some documentation but I am confused how to import Advanced Marker Element.